# how to create dart project and accepts inputs in VScode

Tags: dart

How can I create and run a Dart console application Using VS Code? I tried to accept via vscode. I kept getting "global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded vscode"

Answer (score 0):

Just run with the following command:

```
cd <PROJECT_FOLDER>
dart run bin/<NAME_OF_YOUR_DART_FILE>.dart
```

Comment: You are running it a terminal right? Just pass params.